# Customer Logout using CURL request

Tags: magento2, php, curl

I want to logout customer from external request based on the customer ID.

For example, I have created custom controller action that accepts customer email in a GET request. I want to perform logout operation for that user.

I have written code to logout customer programmatically. But when I execute curl request, customer did not logs-out. I have tried everything but couldn't find the solution.

URL to perform logout: http://magento.local/sso/logout?user=example@mail.com

In short, I want to perform user logout operation based on user email via CURL.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: I want exactly same action to be performed via cURL request as same action performed via browser request